# ERROR TypeError: data.map is not a function

Tags: angular

I get that error on my console, which I don't know how to fix

ERROR TypeError: data.map is not a function

```
list(pageNumber: number = 1, pageSize: number = 10): Observable<any[]> {
        const params = new HttpParams()
          .set('pageNumber', `${pageNumber}`)
          .set('pageSize', `${pageSize}`);

        return this.api.get(this.apiController, { params })
          .pipe(map(data => data.map(item => {
            const picture = `${this.api.apiUrl}/${this.apiController}/${item.id}/photo`;
            return { ...item, picture };
          })));
      }
```

Comment: There is a Spanish Stackoverflow site: https://es.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `array.prototype.map()` method on the response from the HTTP request. `data` is not an array so it does not have a `map()` method. I would recommend using a tool like Postman to confirm that your API is returning what you are expecting.